# TTStyledTextLabel issue with URL's

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I have added a TTStyledTextLabel inside my CustomCell for my UITableView, the code is:

```
  TTStyledTextLabel * tt_title = [[[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, cell.frame.origin.y, 640, 200)] autorelease];
    tt_title.text = [TTStyledText textWithURLs:[[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] message]];
    tt_title.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    tt_title.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    [tt_title sizeToFit];
    [cell addSubview:tt_title
```

];

The NSString passed in has a URL, however when I click on the URL it doesn't do anything.. not even opening it up in safari.. why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly without seeing what is in the actual string you're passing in to TTStyledText, but as an alternative you could try using

```
[TTStyledText textFromXHTML:[[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] message] lineBreaks:NO URLs:YES];
```

and add `<a href=''></a>` to your string

Comment: the string is just @"This is the test at www.youtube.com"

Comment: this is inside the TTTableViewCell

Comment: Tried your code and got the same results, but was able to turn it into a link by adding 'http://' to the front. So I guess the textWithURLs constructor is not that smart. So you have a few options: 1) use textFromXHTML and turn your string into markup with href anchors, 2) add http:// to the front of your links, or 3) modify the TTStyledText source to accept just 'www.'. hope that helps!